# Sensitivity analysis adding new constraint to the simplex method final tableau

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I don't know how to do this exercise:

Minimize-2x1 + x2 -x3

s.t x1+2x2+x3<=8

-x1+x2-2x3<=4

x1,x2,x3>=0

Final table:

---

Base z | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | RHS

z | 1 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 16

x1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 8

x5 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 12

sopuse that the following constraint is added to the proble: x2+2x3=3. Using sensitivity analysis, finde the new optimal solution.